# Are there models of smartphones designed to run on AC adapter/extern power supply permanently?

Tags: battery, charging

Basically, I want to use a smartphone as a fixed position audio player (and rarely for browsing), so I'm thinking, I could use a second hand smartphone for this. However, I'd like to have it plugged in DC power supply 24/7 - but I know most smarpthones are designed to damage the battery if you charge it permanently, so there is more waste and you buy more and spend more money.

So I was wondering - are there smartphones/smartphone models, that are designed to run off an adapter 24/7? As in, maybe they have a setting that you can turn on while plugged on extern DC power, which from that point on disconnects the battery altogether?

Comment: Some Android devices have a "battery preserving" feature which limits charging to below 40% and stops charging at 60%. Especially on Lenovo devices I have seen such a feature. This reduces the damage a 24/7 connected device can do to it's battery, but of course the battery will still charge and discharge and so degrade over the time.